I want to know different file structures for big react projects
I know a few different ways to structure React projects. One of them is basically separating everything in simple folders like components, hooks, contexts, utils, etc., but this separation quickly inflates as the project grows.
Another way I know is to separate things in a tree, just like:
|-components/-|-keyboard/-|-components/-|-key.tsx
|             |           |-hooks/      |-cable.tsx
|             |           |             |-base.tsx
|             |           |-keyboard.tsx
|             |-another component/ ...
|-hooks/ ...

Which feels like incentivizes me componentize more the project, since I can break components into subcomponents without polluting the root components folder with things there are used only in once place.
I have also figured out that you can break the structure in modules, just like:
|-assets/
|-modules/
|    |--core/
|    |    |--componts/
|    |    |--hooks/
|    |    |--utils/
|    |--payment/
|    |     |--components/
|    |     |      |--PaymentForm.tsx
|    |     |--hooks/ ...
|    |--auth/
|    |   |--components/
|    |   |--services/
.   ... ...

There is also Atomic Design, which I don't like much because disincentivizes me to componentize a little bit, since I would have to put each part of a same component in much different places.
In how many other ways can I structure my folders in a React project so that it scales well and keeps everything well organized?
